# Looping a react native animated animation

Tags: react-native

I am attempting to put the following animation in an infinite loop until a particular state occurs:

```
class MyModal extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.springValue = new Animated.Value(0.3)
    }

    spring = () => {
        this.springValue.setValue(0.3)
        Animated.spring(
            this.springValue,
            {
                toValue: 1,
                friction: 1,
                tension: 1,
                duration:5000

            }
        ).start()
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.spring()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Modal
                    animationType="none"
                    transparent={false}
                    visible={this.state.modalVisible}
                    onRequestClose={() => null}
                >
                    <View style={styles.backgroundStyle}>                       
                        <Animated.Image 
                            source={require("./my-awesome-image.png")} 
                            style={{ width: 143, height: 125, top: 100, transform: [{scale: this.springValue}]}}
                        />
                    </View>
                </Modal>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Everything here works great, the animation completes once (as I'm not looping anywhere).

How do I keep my `Animated.Image` looping until I reach a particular state? I just want it infinite looping and the ability to either stop the animation or start another animation when I'm ready to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass a callback to the start function to check whether to restart the animation. You could break it down to something like this:

```js
    onSpringCompletion = () => {
      if (arbitraryCondition) {
        this.spring();
      }
    }

    spring = () => {
          this.springValue.setValue(0.3)
          Animated.spring(
              this.springValue,
              {
                  toValue: 1,
                  friction: 1,
                  tension: 1,
                  duration:5000

              }
          ).start(this.onSpringCompletion);
      }
```

Comment: Maybe it is worth considering that the callback function passed to the .start method takes an object like so : `{ finished: Boolean }`, it allows you to ensure that the next call to animate will be done without any animation being in-progress or scheduled or whatever, also it allows you to stop the animation whenever you want since calling the AnimatedValue.stopAnimation() method will change the o.finished to false thus not restarting the animation (just if you need control over it of course (:)

Answer (score 12):

Store your animation in a variable you can access and just wrap your animation with `Animated.loop()`. Then you can freely use `.start()` and `.stop()` on that variable holding the animation as you please.

So something like this should do:

```
this.springAnimation = Animated.loop(
  Animated.spring(
    this.springValue,
    {
      toValue: 1,
      friction: 1,
      tension: 1,
      duration:5000
    }
  ).start()
)
```

You can find more information about that here:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html#loop

Comment: This should absolutely be selected as the correct answer.

Answer (score -3):

You can use setInterval to keep the animation playing and remove the interval whenever you want. I would do this:

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.interval = setInterval(() => this.spring(), 5000) // Set this time higher than your animation duration
}

... 
// Some where in your code that changes the state
clearInterval(this.interval)
...
```

Comment: setInterval may have unintentional delays which will appear to the user within the animation loop